# ngx-bootstrap datepicker doesnt work

Tags: angular

I am learning about angular2 and bootstrap4. My company uses the following site.
http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker
The calendar showed up but if I click something, nothing happens.
I have no idea why the site can't be moved. Could you anyone help me?

*app.component.html:

```
<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <div class="card">
    <pre class="card-block card-header">Selected date is: <em *ngIf="dt">{{ getDate() | date:'fullDate'}}</em></pre>
  </div>
  <h4>Inline</h4>
  <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="dt" [minDate]="minDate" [showWeeks]="true" [dateDisabled]="dateDisabled"></datepicker>
  </div>

  <hr />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" (click)="today()">Today</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-secondary" (click)="d20090824();">2009-08-24</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-secondary" (click)="toggleMin()" tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-secondary" (click)="disableTomorrow()">Disable Tomorrow</button>
</div>
```

*app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';
import { TypeaheadModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/typeahead';
import { ButtonsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/buttons';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    DatepickerModule.forRoot(), ButtonsModule.forRoot(), TypeaheadModule.forRoot(), PaginationModule.forRoot(), ModalModule.forRoot(), BsDropdownModule.forRoot(), BrowserModule, FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
export class DemoDropdownBasicLinkComponent {
  public items: string[] = ['The first choice!',
    'And another choice for you.', 'but wait! A third!'];

  public onHidden(): void {
    console.log('Dropdown is hidden');
  }
  public onShown(): void {
    console.log('Dropdown is shown');
  }
  public isOpenChange(): void {
    console.log('Dropdown state is changed');
  }
}
export class DemoButtonsRadioComponent {
  public radioModel: string = 'Middle';
}
export class DemoButtonsBasicComponent {
  public singleModel: string = '1';
}
export class DemoButtonsDisabledComponent {
  public disabled: boolean = true;

}
export class DatepickerDemoComponent {
  public dt: Date = new Date();
  public minDate: Date = void 0;
  public events: any[];
  public tomorrow: Date;
  public afterTomorrow: Date;
  public dateDisabled: {date: Date, mode: string}[];
  public formats: string[] = ['DD-MM-YYYY', 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    'shortDate'];
  public format: string = this.formats[0];
  public dateOptions: any = {
    formatYear: 'YY',
    startingDay: 1
  };
  private opened: boolean = false;

  public constructor() {
    (this.tomorrow = new Date()).setDate(this.tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    (this.afterTomorrow = new Date()).setDate(this.tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
    (this.minDate = new Date()).setDate(this.minDate.getDate() - 1000);
    (this.dateDisabled = []);
    this.events = [
      {date: this.tomorrow, status: 'full'},
      {date: this.afterTomorrow, status: 'partially'}
    ];
  }

  public getDate(): number {
    return this.dt && this.dt.getTime() || new Date().getTime();
  }

  public today(): void {
    this.dt = new Date();
  }

  public d20090824(): void {
    this.dt = moment('2009-08-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      .toDate();
  }

  public disableTomorrow(): void {
    this.dateDisabled = [{date: this.tomorrow, mode: 'day'}];
  }

  // todo: implement custom class cases
  public getDayClass(date: any, mode: string): string {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      let dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

      for (let event of this.events) {
        let currentDay = new Date(event.date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return event.status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  }

  public disabled(date: Date, mode: string): boolean {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  }

  public open(): void {
    this.opened = !this.opened;
  }

  public clear(): void {
    this.dt = void 0;
    this.dateDisabled = undefined;
  }

  public toggleMin(): void {
    this.dt = new Date(this.minDate.valueOf());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic rule of angular: All the methods and values used in a template should be in the component which it is referring to.

In your case, app.component.html is being referred in AppComponent. And you are referring to the Methods which you have defined in DatepickerDemoComponent.

No matter how many classes you export inside app.component.ts, but the template can only access models and methods from the class which has the @Component annotation on top of it.

Eg: The template tries to find getDate() method inside AppComponent class since it does not has any such method it will throw an error. You can see it in the browser console.

Try moving all the methods and models defined in **Buttons and DatePicker Components** to AppComponent. It should work.

Comment: this is new issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715315/module-users-my-app4-src-app-datepicker-datepicker-component-has-no-exp angular is quite difficult for me X(